# How to write this kind of a mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I want to write this kind of a MySQL query.

```
select image_path, replace(replace(replace(description,\'/images/\',image_path),\'<![CDATA[\',\'\'),\']]>\',\'\') description from test_image_master where ...
```

If I echo this query from php it is showing like this

```
select image_path, replace(replace(replace(description,'/images/',image_path),'','') description from test_image_master where ...
```

Missing `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`. So the query is not working properly.

I am using php and mysql.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is your goal with this, in what way do you need to fix the database results? Where are you querying these things from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't miss. You just can't see from browser, you can check the source of html.